# Creating folder in Android/data/com.yourpakagename/mydirectory

Tags: directory, internal

I am trying to create a folder in Android/data/com.yourpakagename/mydirectory
I have used this code.But it creates folder in internal.

```
public void Createfol(){
File mediaStorageDir = new File(Environment.getExternalStorageDirectory(), "MyNew directory");
if (!mediaStorageDir.exists()) {
    if (!mediaStorageDir.mkdirs()) {
        Log.d("App", "failed to create directory");
      //  return null;
    }
    else {
        Log.d("Apppppp", "create directory");
    }
}
```

But I want to create folder in data/com.packagename directory.I also used this code for creation

```
    File myfolder = getFilesDir();
    File f = new File(myfolder, "aaaaa");
    f.mkdir();
    if (!f.exists())
        if (!f.mkdir()) {
            Toast.makeText(this, myfolder + " can't be created.", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();

        } else
            Toast.makeText(this, myfolder + " can be created.", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
    else
        Toast.makeText(this, myfolder + " already exits.", Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
```

Toast is showing already exist when each time runs,but I am not able to visible com.packagename directory.What is the problem in this?

Comment: folder can can be seen in Device FileExplorer :)

Answer (score 0):

My folder is created.It can be seen by using Device file Explorer.(View->New window->Device file Explorer).we can find the created folder in data->data->com.yourpackagename->files->my folder.